# How implement the slash screen for android in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using this library `react-native-bootsplash` from https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash
, I made these steps:

I edited the android/build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 23 // <- AndroidX splashscreen has basic support for 21 (only the background color), so 23 is best
    compileSdkVersion = 31 // <- set at least 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31 // <- set at least 31
```

Then edit your android/app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  // …

  implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
  implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0" // Add this line

  // …
```

Edit your `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` file:

```
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
      <!-- Your base theme customization -->
  </style>

  <!-- BootTheme should inherit from Theme.SplashScreen -->
  <style name="BootTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/bootsplash_background</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/bootsplash_logo</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Edit your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.rnbootsplashexample">

  <!-- … -->

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/BootTheme"> <!-- Replace @style/AppTheme with @style/BootTheme -->
    <!-- … -->
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Finally edit your `android/app/src/main/java/com/yourprojectname/MainActivity.java` file:

```
// …

// Add these required imports:
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplash;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  // …

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RNBootSplash.init(this); // <- initialize the splash screen
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // or super.onCreate(null) with react-native-screens
  }
}
```

But it does not show the icon in the splash screen

Answer (score 0):

1. You should generate the icons (if you haven't) with `yarn react-native generate-bootsplash <logoPath>`
2. Clean the build folder with `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`
   before running your app.